# Compare values in select statement and insert into new table

Tags: sql-server

I have a column where the values need to be cleansed. I would like to find a way where I can directly compare the values from my select distinct statement and compare with all the values in the column and insert into a new table

Currently I am using a case statement but that is taking too long because the distinct values are many. I dont want to type them, is there an easier way that I can do this

```
select id, name, 
case category
   when 'Madras' then 'Chennai'
   when 'Madres' then 'Chennai'
   when 'Medres' then 'Chennai'
   when 'Bombay' then 'Mumbai'
   when is null then 'unknown'
   else 'default values'
 end
from city
```

Comment: prepare a mapping table and join with it

Comment: In other word, create a table that contain 2 column like Col1  'Chennai',Col2 'Madras'.Then LEFT join with col1 and update col2